# Чем отличаются сервисы от репозиториев?

Tags: php, laravel

Часто советуют выносить некоторую логику в сервисы, а некоторую в репозитории.
Подскажите, в чём разница между сервисами (App\Services) и репозиториями (App\Repositories) ?
Ведь в них подготавливаются начальные данные.
И второй вопрос, допустим в папке `css/critical` лежат критикал-стили для разных страниц.

```
css/critical/home.css  
css/critical/product.css   
css/critical/about.css
```

нужно для разных страниц выбирать соотвествующие критикал-стили, допустим по имени роутера.
Подскажите, куда выносить эту логику по выборке этих стилей, в сервисы или репозитории?

Comment: и если имеются разные типы записи, к примеру категории и статьи, и у них должен быть метод save() и update() для сохранения соответствующей записи, нужно ли создавать единый интерфейс для этого, т.е. чтобы категории и статьи реализовывали единый интерфейс save, update? и соответственно куда выносить эту логику (контроллер, сервис, репозиторий)?

Comment: репо - это бд. достать, сохранить модель из бд, достать с подвыпертом. А сервис - это услуга, любая. В принципе репо частный случай сервиса. и получается надо в контроллере сходить во внешний сервер, что-то достать и положить в (обновить) свою модель: сервис доставания один класс в сервисах, медель в сущностях, репо в репозитариях как частный случай сервисов по работе с моделями. в контроллере подключается и сервис, и репо.

Comment: @mpakfm, подскажите, а куда выносить выборку критикал-стилей? В общий контроллер, от которого наследуются все контроллеры?

Comment: @mpakfm, приведите пожалуйста пример, какие сущности следует пихать в сервисы, а какие в репозитории, к примеру вышеприведённые стили куда нужно впихнуть?

Comment: Для работы со статикой я бы посоветовал изучить вебпак encore

Comment: @mpakfm, это? http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/10939  для чего он?

Comment: https://symfony.ru/doc/current/frontend.html - encore
https://symfony.ru/doc/current/frontend/encore/versus-assetic.html - encore vs assetic